# Setting environment variable through NSIS Envar-plugin

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables, installation, nsis

I have a custom installer created through NSIS.

I have the following Ant task doing the same:

```
<target name="buildNSIS">
    <exec executable="D:\NSIS\nsis-binary\makensis.exe" failonerror="true" >
      <!-- providing some nsis definitions -->
      <arg value="/DPROJECT_NAME=${ant.project.name}"/>
      <!-- passing the script -->
      <arg value=".\installer\MySetup.nsi"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

where `MySetup.nsi` is the script to run through NSIS for the installer.

I want to set an environment variable as part of the install process.

I read that its best to do using: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/EnVar_plug-in

However, the instruction there is confusing. It just says: **Just extract the contents to your nsis directory (usually '$PROGRAMFILES\NSIS')**

What does it mean?

My `D:\NSIS\nsis-binary` directory looks like:

[image]

So do I unzip `Envar_plugin.zip` inside `Plugins` directory above and start using `EnVar::AddValue` or `EnVar::AddValueEx` functions inside my `MySetup.nsi` as mentioned in `Envar_plugin` examples?

How do I use `Envar_plugin` so that my resultant custom installer through `MySetup.nsi` for my software will set environment variables during installation of my software?

Comment: Just do literally what it says.

Comment: Were you able to edit the path env variable using this? I'm not finding the documentation for how to make a call to edit the path env var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug-ins have to be installed in the correct plug-in subdirectory inside the NSIS folder. Some plug-ins only have a .DLL file in the root of the .ZIP file and some already have the correct directory tree in the .ZIP. This specific plug-in has the latter and you can just extract the contents to your main NSIS folder.

If you try to execute a plug-in command (`name::function`) and NSIS cannot find the plug-in then you most likely put the .DLL file in the wrong folder. Recent versions of NSIS will print a list of directories it tried to search when this happens.

Comment: Thanks.. my confusion was between the following three places: D:\NSIS\nsis-binary, D:\NSIS\nsis-binary\bin and D:\NSIS\nsis-binary\Plugins... from the answers and comments it seems I have to unzip it in D:\NSIS\nsis-binary directory and not in D:\NSIS\nsis-binary\bin and D:\NSIS\nsis-binary\Plugins.. Please correct if am wrong..

Comment: Yes, correct. The compiler will stop if it can't find the plug-in so you always know if you did it wrong.